# Does dissolving a solute lowers the activation energy of a reaction of that solute?

Tags: thermodynamics, solutions, solvents

I'm formulating a reason why the use of solvents in some reactants are preferred rather then mixing just the pure components together. My gut feeling tells me that it lowers the activation energy of the reaction but, I can't find explicite answers to confirm my guess. Can someone help me with this :)?

Comment: Dissolution may or may not affect the activation energy, but there is a factor more important than that. See, you can't **really** mix two solid compounds on molecular level, even if you grind them together very thoroughly.